# What do these arrows on a pinout represent?

Tags: datasheet, pinout, dma

What do these arrows represent?
Is there any way to memorize it easily?

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, why would you need to memorise them?

Comment: This is precisely what these arrows are here for: to designate signal directions, so you don't need to "memorize" the major pin function.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff i have a test on microprocessors . i have to draw pin config and architecture of various processors .

Comment: Argh; I used to hate stuff like that. The good news is that, in the real world, you can refer to datasheets as often as you like. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They indicate data direction. Arrows pointing to the chip indicate that those pins are inputs and vice versa. Bidirectional arrows indicate they are either inputs/outputs, depending on the circumstances.

If you want to memorize it, I think you should memorize those pins meanings first.

Comment: yea i have memorized the pins , the problem is that some pins  have 2 arrows and some dont .

Comment: @MarkHenry The double arrows represent pins that are bidirectional - may be either input or output, depending on the circumstances.